# Can a browser extension's browser_action script save data to a user-specified file?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

My extension has a lot of options and users can save other data, and all of it is in browser.storage.local. I'd like to provide an option to export the data to a JSON file. From a regular page script, I'd use Blob() and saveAs, but saveAs is undefined in the browser_action context I'm using for my settings page which is the natural home for the option.

My extension uses nativeMessaging so I can send the data to my host-based process and do the save from there, but if I prompt the user for where to save it from the host process, that will cause a switch that they probably wouldn't anticipate. I haven't implemented this, so perhaps that would be OK.

My direction question is: **Can the JavaScript for a browser extension's browser_action page save a file to the user's device based on the user clicking a button?**

I am targeting Chrome and Firefox only and Windows platform only. I'll add support for Mac later after I port the host process.

Comment: Extensions can't do that. The upcoming Native File System API can do that. Regarding your native host app, it should be possible to display the file dialog without the app's UI and set the dialog's opener handle to HWND of the browser window so the focus will stay. Look into WINAPI or whatever framework you're using.

Comment: @wOxxOm, thanks for that information. I don't think I can wait for the Native File System API, so its off to host land I go.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `downloads.download()`? https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/download For example:

```
const data = JSON.stringify({ boolean: true }, null, 2);
browser.downloads.download({
  url: URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], { type: 'application/json' })),
  saveAs: true,
  filename: 'file.json'
});
```